# How do I theme a webform?

Tags: 7, webforms, theming

I am in need to theme webform in D7.

How can I do that ?

In the search I've come to know that by using web-form-nid.tpl.php we are able to theme a drupal individual form.

Could any one guide me in this case to theme a webform.

Comment: There is a THEMING.TXT included with the module: http://drupalcode.org/project/webform.git/blob/HEAD:/THEMING.txt, which is listed on the module's documentation page under THEMING: http://drupal.org/documentation/modules/webform

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can theme a individual webform using `webform-form-nid.tpl.php`.

For example if our webform node id is 7 , create a template file namely `webform-form-7.tpl.php` and place it in your theme folder. Clear site cache.

Do a `print_r($form);` to see all the elements. Then render each elements in file within your html elements.

```
<li>
    <?php print drupal_render($form['submitted']['name']); ?>
</li>
```

As  @Patrick Kenny said read the [theming.txt](http://drupalcode.org/project/webform.git/blob/HEAD:/THEMING.txt), it explain all aspects of theming a webform

Comment: I can't figure out how to render the submit button, please can you help

Comment: Can you specify what have been you tried so far and where you struck at?   The submit button can render by something like this <?php
 print render(drupal_render($form['submit']));
?>  Do a print_r($form); for better understanding.

Comment: Or, alternatively, to render submit, you can just do: <?php print drupal_render_children($form); ?>. It will render everything else that you haven't specifically rendered, which for my form I'm working on now is just the submit button.

Answer (score 4):

If you know the .tpl.php filename, here is what you do:

- Create empty file with that name in your theme. Element it was supposed to template disappeared? Good.
- Put simple html tag and see if it is displayed in place of your element. It is? Great, you have correct template file.
- See all variables you can use: place `<pre><?php print_r(get_defined_vars()); ?></pre>` in your template.
- Now when you have a file and data structure, just do it!