# Transforming a Webform upload field into a single Attach button

Tags: forms, webforms, theming

I want to transform the entire **"Browse No file selected Upload"** to a button like **"Submit"** nellens.com/home/content/contact, using CSS, I don´t know if this is possible. It is made with Webforms!

[image]
[image]

Comment: You need to theme that element. [Here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/74564/16495) is a generic answer. Specific part will not apply to you, but it should give you a pointer about "where to start".

Comment: I got it! Thanks for the answer I will get into this, I need to understand better the php code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found these 2 tutorials, with this I can manipulate the upload field only with CSS, without touching the PHP code:

http://jsfiddle.net/gabrieleromanato/mxq9R/

http://geniuscarrier.com/how-to-style-a-html-file-upload-button-in-pure-css/

With this, it creates the link based on an image as background that imitate the form of the button.

Thanks again to @Mołot for helping.