# HTML in webform labels

Tags: webforms, theming

I need to insert HTML markup (spans, classes, h2 tags). However, webform appears to be filtering out all markup from labels. Has anybody succeeded in inserting html markup in labels, and how did you do that?

Comment: Just a note - an h2 can't go inside a label, it's invalid HTML

Comment: See this question: [How to theme a webform](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/73713/how-to-theme-a-webform-d7)

Comment: Hey Felix, using templates or preprocesses is of course an option. Though, I would really like to know how come the html is preserved in my client's webform labels, but not in mine. I pulled the code base thru git, and imported the db. Something really differs.

Comment: Does it need to be in the label, or could you just use a Markup webform component?

Comment: Yes I ended up doing it as #markup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to use HTML markup within the label inputs within the Webform module itself, as it most likely cleans out all HTML markup before displaying to the user to prevent XSS attacks etc.

Most likely you'll need to write a small custom module which implements **hook_form_alter**, which will allow you to change the markup used for the labels.

I'm not actually sure if Drupal will allow markup within the **#title** attribute of your form elements, so you might need to use the **#prefix** property instead to add your custom HTML replacement labels.

If this is all Greek to you then you'll probably need to checkout these tutorials:

[Creating modules - a tutorial: Drupal 7.x](https://drupal.org/node/1074360)

[Hook snippets: hook_form_alter](https://drupal.org/node/651106)

Comment: My client has the same code base, that I pulled though git. And in his stage environment, the html in labels works. (Though xss javascripts are filtered). We share the same codebase. This is surrealistic.

Comment: how are you setting the labels then? Via the Webform's GUI?

Comment: I am setting labels via webform GUI. And html in labels  works and shows in his dev environment but not in mine. We run the same code base, and we run the same php version.

Comment: hmmm that's very strange. I can't think of any reason off hand for the different results. This method seems a bit hacky to me, I'd personally rather implement my method above so that your specials labels can be commited to your git repo too.

Comment: Yes, this this very strange. I will keep diggind and post findings if I succeed. If not - then I will just use templates and preprocesses.

Comment: Sharing the same code base means very little here - Drupal stores most of its config in the database. Take a copy of your clients db and try running that locally - if it doesn't work, then yeah, you're in bang-head-against-the-wall territory - but I'd be willing to bet you'll actually find it works the same as the live client site, meaning you just need to change a setting somewhere

Comment: Clive, yes. I don't think that heaven would interfered on my behalf and work a miracle in one of the two cases. So its somehting somewhere. As far as I understand, the output in labels is actually stripped of tags. No one has claimed that it 'should work with html' so far.

Comment: It is some setting in database. Will tell when I find it.

Comment: The client has been using the latest webform 4.x dev, and has set the input format to a custom format, that has had all filters disabled. That made the html in labels work.

Answer (score 2):

I added the following to the bottom of my settings.php page.  I read it somewhere... works like a charm. :)

```
$conf['webform_allowed_tags'] = array('a', 'em', 'strong', 'code', 'img', 'ul', 'li', 'u', 'span style="font-style:italic', 'span' , 'a', 'i', 'italic');
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I need to remember this intuitive way to allow the tags I need to display!

Answer (score 0):

the  "Options with Markup" module allows HTML formatting of labels for radio button/checkbox.https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_optionsmarkup

Answer (score 0):

In D8+, you can do this via copying the twig template that generated the `label` markup.

Copy `core/modules/system/templates/form-element-label.html.twig` to your theme and change as needed. Just ensure the markup you add is valid HTML.

In my case, I had to add a `span` if the field was required:

```
 {%
  set classes = [
    title_display == 'after' ? 'option',
    title_display == 'invisible' ? 'visually-hidden',
    required ? 'js-form-required',
    required ? 'form-required',
  ]
%}
{% if title is not empty or required -%}
  {% if required %}
    <label{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>{{ title }}<span class="sr-only"> required</label>
  {% else %}
    <label{{ attributes.addClass(classes) }}>{{ title }}</label>
  {% endif %}
{%- endif %}
```

I originally tried modifying the `label` via `hook_form_alter()`, but webforms seem not to spit out the same elements to alter i.e. `$form['FIELD_NAME']['widget'][0]['value']['#title']`.