# Custom preview page on Webform

Tags: 7, webforms

I want to theming only preview pages on Webform. Is it possible?

Comment: Yes. Drupal is written in PHP, therefore it will be possible.

Comment: Well, is there a good and easy solution for this? I mean, create a tpl files and edit it.

Comment: What are "good" and "easy" in this context? Don't make me drag this out of you, if you want some help, ask a proper, **specific** question! :)

Comment: I mean, can I create a webform--preview.tpl.php file?

Comment: Ok, getting somewhere. Please edit your question and describe exactly what it is you want to do, that will help it to remain opened, and you to hopefully receive some answers. Hint: your question will be at least a couple of paragraphs long, not a single line.

Answer (score 1):

I find two solution links, please check them:

Sol-1: https://www.drupal.org/node/1430034 (Most relevant solution)

Sol-2: [How to theme a webform - D7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/73713/how-to-theme-a-webform-d7) (It another solution to theme webform with another tpl name: webform-form.tpl.php. Here is the [link](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!webform!templates!webform-form.tpl.php/7) which provide tpl code.)

I guess you need to use node--webform.tpl.php and also add preprocessor in template.php.

```
function themeName_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
  if (isset($vars['node'])) {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__'. $vars['node']->type;
  }
}
```

And when you create tpl file you can check preview variable to check and theme accordingly.

If this doesn't help try second solution.

See similar issue [here](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/215393/webforms-preview-tpl-page/).

Answer (score 0):

You fill find it very hard to do this in a tpl.

Use a form_alter hook and check if you are on the preview step:

```
$page_count = $form_state['webform']['page_count'];
$page_num = $form_state['webform']['page_num'];
$preview = $form_state['webform']['preview'];
if ($preview && $page_num === $page_count) {
   ...
}
```