# How can I theme the webforms preview page, and what's the template file for it?

Tags: 7, theming, webforms

I want to alter some data on preview page of a Webform and I want to add a template file for it.

How can I theme the webforms preview page, and what's the template file for it?

Answer (score 1):

I find two solution links, please check them:

Sol-1: https://www.drupal.org/node/1430034 (Most relevant solution)

Sol-2: [How to theme a webform - D7](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/73713/how-to-theme-a-webform-d7) (It another solution to theme webform with another tpl name: webform-form.tpl.php. Here is the [link](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!webform!templates!webform-form.tpl.php/7) which provide tpl code.)

I guess you need to use node--webform.tpl.php and also add preprocessor in template.php.

```
function themeName_preprocess_page(&$vars, $hook) {
  if (isset($vars['node'])) {
    $vars['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'page__'. $vars['node']->type;
  }
}
```

And when you create tpl file you can check preview variable to check and theme accordingly.

If this doesn't help try second solution.

Comment: @Pierre.Vriens thanks for your comment. Added detailed answer with my suggested solution.

Comment: Those links are relevant and will surely help

Comment: Sure adding phrases.

Comment: Edited the main answer.

Comment: ***Voilà***, that is a nice answer!