# Extract webform result by using php

Tags: 7, database, webforms

I have eight pages using this same webform.
My webform have two fields: email and "get current URL".
My Thank you page (when submitted webform) URL link state sid = "88".
I DO NOT want "thank you page" same design, so I decide to get URL sid and search for "get current URL" through database. From the result will base on my design.

Here is my question: I do not know how to retrieve data from database? OR Is there anybetter way to achieve what I want?

Comment: you can theme webform using sid in template file

Comment: @Adi, Do you mind explain more in detail? :) I quite new to drupal. I never touch template before.

Comment: check this link http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/73713/how-to-theme-a-webform-d7