# Webform multipage - different page.tpl for different page

Tags: theming, webforms

Is it possible to use specific `page.tpl` for webform pages?

For example: `page--form1.tpl` for page 1 and `page--form2.tpl` for page 2.

I wanted to do this via URL but it's same on all pages.

Any ideas?

Comment: the page or just the webform? check this: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/73713/how-to-theme-a-webform-d7

Comment: Only the page...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this on page level. Can't you use form templates? In that case you could add your own theme functions. Here's an example:

```
/**
 * Implements hook_theme().
 */
function YOUR_TEMPLATE_OR_MODULE_theme() {
  // Add our own webform theme function, copied from
  // webform_form in webform.module.
  $theme = array(
    'webform_form_page' => array(
      'render element' => 'form',
      'template' => 'templates/webform-form',
      'pattern' => 'webform_form_[0-9]+_[0-9]+',
    ),
  );
  return $theme;
}

/**
 * Implements hook_webform_form_webform_client_form_alter().
 */
function YOUR_TEMPLATE_OR_MODULE_webform_form_webform_client_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  // Check if we are on another page then 1 in a webform.
  if (isset($form_state['storage']['page_num'])) {
    // Add our own theme including the page number.
    $form['#theme'][] = 'webform_form_' . $form['#node']->nid . '_' . $form_state['storage']['page_num'];
  }
}
```

You should now be able to create your own tpl file per form page. It would look something like this: **webform-form-626-2.tpl** where 626 is the node id and 2 is the page number. For the first page you should just use **webform-form-626.tpl.php** so it also functions as a fallback template.

I haven't tested this so you might need to tweak it a bit but I hope this puts you on the right way.